# Modifying a paragraph added using InsertParagraphAfter()

Tags: c#, ms-word

```
var p1 = document.Paragraphs.Add(ref o);
p1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Now I want to grab the paragraph that was just created using InsertParagraphAfter() and modify it.  How can I access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InsertParagraphAfter` is supposed to extend the current selection to include the new paragraph.  So if you start by creating an empty selection at the end of the existing paragraph, the current selection should be set to the new paragraph after calling `InsertParagraphAfter`.

Note that I have not tested the following code (I have not even tried compiling it), so I may be way off.

```
var p1 = document.Paragraphs.Add(ref o);    
// Set the selection to the end of the paragraph.
document.Range(p1.Range.End, p1.Range.End).Select();
p1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
// InsertParagraphAfter should expand the active selection to include
// the newly inserted paragraph.
var newParagraph = document.Application.Selection;
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work :(  Maybe you can help me though.  The reason why I'm doing this is to separate two tables so they're not merged by word automatically, but then I want the tables to be stacked one directly on top of the other.  By doing a InsertParagraphAfter(), a whole line break separates the two tables, I want to modify the new paragraph so that the tables are right on top of each other.  Is there  a different way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: @sooprise: Try doing what you want to do in Word while recording a macro and then check out the code in VBA afterwards. Maybe that can give you a hint on how it can be done?

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately didn't yield the result I wanted.

Comment: @sooprise: Can you post some of the code that you already have and perhaps also a screenshot of what you want in Word to help me get a better understanding of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding a new paragraph relatively to the first paragraph:

```
Paragraph p1 = document.Paragraphs.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
p1.Range.Text = "Foo";
p1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

// Add new paragraph relative to first paragraph
Paragraph p2 = document.Paragraphs.Add(p1.Range);
p2.Range.Text = "Bar";
p2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

// Add new paragraph relative to the second paragraph
Paragraph p3 = document.Paragraphs.Add(p2.Range);
p3.Range.Text = "Baz";
```

Comment: According to MSDN when you give a rang to Paragraphs.Add it will create the Paragraphs before the range.

The result of your sample should be something like :

BazBarFoo

If you want something looking like :

Foo
Bar
Baz

You should use the following:

`Paragraph p1 = document.Paragraphs.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
p1.Range.Text = "Foo";
Paragraph p2 = p1.Range.Paragraphs.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
p2.Range.Text = "Bar";
Paragraph p3 = p2.Range.Paragraphs.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
p3.Range.Text = "Baz";`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way old but could not resist.

Here is the working solution (rng is one paragraph's range):

```
    rng.InsertParagraphAfter()
    If rng.Paragraphs(1).Next IsNot Nothing Then
        rng.Paragraphs(1).Next.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleNormal)
    End If
```